# Give default write permission to group to any newly created files and folders

Tags: permissions, group

Let's say that we have 2 users: a and b, that are both part of group general.

I would like that any file or folder that A creates, would have write permission to the group GENERAL.

How can I do it?

For instance, the newly created file is set as:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 a general
```

This doesn't give write permission to the group general

Comment: You might be interested in this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175303/how-can-i-set-the-umask-from-within-java

Comment: I don't want to do it from Java. This is not the right way to do it

Comment: "I don't want to do it from Java. This is not the right way to do it." That's almost a philosophical statement. It applies everywhere...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, you can do that changing the `umask`. The `umask` determines which are the default permissions for a newly creted file.

You can add `umask g+w` at the end of your shell configuration file (`~/.bashrc` for example).

But actually, it´s not a recommendable practice. In the case you do want to ensure the integrity of a file and you forget to update the file permissions, it will be modifiable by the group. It's against the "secure initial values" principle of security.

What you could do instead is make all the newly created file of a *specific* directory writable by the group. You can do this manipulating the ACLs of the directory. For example, `setfacl -dm u::rw,g::rw,o::r ~/shared`.

Look at those posts for reference : https://serverfault.com/questions/349145/can-i-override-my-umask-using-acls-to-make-all-files-created-in-a-given-director and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580584/setting-default-permissions-for-newly-created-files-and-sub-directories-under-a.

Comment: What if I don't know what the directory will be? Since let's say that I have folder TEST. All the files that A creates will be under TEST. However, he could created a folder 20130515 and under it to locate the newly created file. so it should be for any file and folder that is created recursively under TEST folder

Comment: default ACL's inherit to new subdirectories and apply to files created in those directories. So if you have `/srv/TEST` set the default ACL's on that directory then when the `/srv/TEST/20130515` it will have the same default ACL's as the parent directory.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to run `sudo chmod g+s [dir]` so the files will be owned by the group